# Is Jasmine's beforeEach synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

If you have multiple `beforeEach`'s, will they always run one after another?

```
beforeEach(function() {});
beforeEach(function() {});
beforeEach(function() {});
beforeEach(function() {});
beforeEach(function() {});
```

It seems that they will. I tried testing it with my code:

```
describe('Directive: Statement', function() {
  var el, scope, statements;

  beforeEach(module('simulatedSelves'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    console.log(1);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    statements = [];
    scope.statement = {
      text: 'test',
      arr: []
    };
    scope.statement.parent = statements;
    statements.push(scope.statement);

    el = angular.element('<statement statement=statement></statement>');
    $compile(el)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));
  beforeEach(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    console.log(2);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      counter++;
    }
    console.log(counter);
  });
  beforeEach(function() {
    console.log(3);
  });

  it('test statement has correct properties', function() {
    // stuff
  });
});
```

It logs:

```
1
2
1000000
3
```

Since the `beforeEach` with the long `for` loop logs its stuff out before the one that logs `3`, I'm thinking that the `beforeEach`'s run synchronously. Is that true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, all `beforeEach`s will execute in the order you define.

If you drill into Jasmine, you eventually get to [this definition](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/src/core/Suite.js#L45-L47):

```
Suite.prototype.beforeEach = function(fn) {
  this.beforeFns.unshift(fn);
};
```

As you add `describe`s, `Suite`s get generated and nested. Each `Suite` is initialized with `this.beforeFns = []`, which is added to as you can see. Note that `unshift` adds to the left side of the array, so you'd expect later-defined `beforeEach`s to be run first. That's [fixed later](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L553-L570) when Jasmine walks up the child suite's parents, gathers all `beforeEach` lists, and then reverses them to run in the order you want.

```
var beforeAndAfterFns = function(suite) {
  return function() {
    var befores = [],
      afters = [];

    while(suite) {
      befores = befores.concat(suite.beforeFns);
      afters = afters.concat(suite.afterFns);

      suite = suite.parentSuite;
    }

    return {
      befores: befores.reverse(),
      afters: afters
    };
  };
};
```

---

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073868/dan-pantry) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492452/is-jasmines-beforeeach-synchronous/31493267#comment50950030_31493267), we've so far assumed that all of your `beforeEach`s are synchronous. As of Jasmine 2, you can set up asynchronous `beforeEach`s like so:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Async');
    done();
  }, 1000)
});
```

At runtime, Jasmine sends you the `done` function and executes asynchronously [if your function takes an argument](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/src/core/QueueRunner.js#L36-L41). ([Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) returns the number of arguments the function expects).

```
for(iterativeIndex = recursiveIndex; iterativeIndex < length; iterativeIndex++) {
  var queueableFn = queueableFns[iterativeIndex];
  if (queueableFn.fn.length > 0) {
    attemptAsync(queueableFn);
    return;
  } else {
    attemptSync(queueableFn);
  }
}
```

`attemptAsync` waits for you to call `done()` before the `QueueRunner` moves on to the next `beforeEach` hook, so ordering still works! Pretty neat.

```
describe('beforeEach', function() {
  var data = null;

  beforeEach(function() { data = []; });
  beforeEach(function() { data.push(1); });
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      data.push('Async');
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
  beforeEach(function() { data.push(2); });
  beforeEach(function() { data.push(3); });

  it('runs in order', function(){
    expect(data).toEqual([1, 'Async', 2, 3]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Jasmine also supports asynchronous `beforeEach` with promises and callbacks, though, so I don't think it's quite as cut-and-try as this

Comment: Very good point, now I'm digging in to see how [QueueRunner](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4be20794827a63ca5295848c58ffc478624ee4dc/src/core/QueueRunner.js) works.

Comment: @DanPantry Updated with async behavior, and I learned a lot. Thanks!