# Angular Karma tests with Webpack fail injection

Tags: angularjs, webpack, karma-jasmine

I've a rather large Angular project written in Typescript which I've got working with Webpack. This produces a bundle which loads in the browser and all is fine.

Now I'm trying to run the few Karma tests I have so far which used to work when transpiled to Javascript on disk. To make things easier after a 2 days of trial and error is that I am now running a single test. What happens is the Webpack step runs and Karma tries to run the test in PhantomJS. It gives the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'browser.url') in /vagrant/itracker/media/website/js/test/admin/controllers/colsumObjectController.spec.ts (line 73)`

This means the `browser` variable has not been set by the injection step. Indeed, I have added a console log to the function and it never executes.

```
    describe("ColsumObjectController", () => {
        const allColsumObjectsForProcess = { "count": 4, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": []};
        const allColsumOptions = { "count": 6, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": []};
        const allColsumFieldsForProcess = { "count": 6, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": []};

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('adminApp'));

        var controller, browser, httpBackend, $scope, colsumObjectController;

        console.log('1. *****************************');
        beforeEach(angular.mock.inject( (_$controller_, _$browser_, _$httpBackend_) => {
            console.log(_$browser_);
            console.log('2. *****************************');
            controller = _$controller_;
            browser = _$browser_;
            httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {

            console.log('3. *****************************');
            $scope = {};
            browser.url('http://127.0.0.1/process/admin/colsum-object-list-view/2/');

            httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/v1/colsum-objects/?process=2').respond(200, allColsumObjectsForProcess);
            httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/v1/colsum-options/').respond(200, allColsumOptions);
            httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/v1/colsum-fields/?process=2&page_size=9999').respond(200, allColsumFieldsForProcess);

            colsumObjectController = controller('ColsumObjectController', {$scope: $scope});

            httpBackend.flush();
        });
 // Rest of test
```

Output:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: '1. *****************************'

LOG: '3. *****************************'
```

So you can see that step 2 doesn't get executed. Why is this?

Comment: Everything looks good but I have been taking a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492452/is-jasmines-beforeeach-synchronous It could be that your third beforeEach executes before the second one is done. Take a look and let me know if it helped

Comment: It looks as though the inject just never happens so this looks like an issue with Angular and not Jasmine. I just can't see why this never executes.

Comment: Same problem here. By instrumenting `angular-mocks` I can see that this line seems to just stop the execution of the inject: `injector = currentSpec.$injector = angular.injector(modules, strictDi);`. A log before is logged, a log after is not. Not exception, nothing...

Comment: Turns out that I was trying to load an unknown module. Angular throw an exception but the beforeEach is masking it.